# Video (HTML5) not getting currenttime from javascript on Chrome mobile and Android native browser

Tags: javascript, android, html5-video

This is very strange, but when I execute this on my chrome developer tools (inspecting my device):

```
$('video').get(0).currentTime = 5
```

and then hit play, my video starts from 0. However, if I do this:

```
$('video').get(0).currentTime = 5.1
```

and then hit play, my video then starts from 5.

It is like if there was some kind of interval and the video was split in sections of 5 seconds when playing on Android. How can i set exactly the second I want as current time?

What I want to achieve, is that when I pause and then play my video, keep the current time as it keeps jumping back to the previous "interval".

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Have you tried `5.0`. Maybe it's looking for a decimal type.

Comment: Just tried, doesn't work... Thanks a lot anyway

Comment: Just an update, the interval is of 10 seconds. It jumps 10 seconds before or after, depending on what I set. It is like a round()

Comment: Try this [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/15d5yzbx/4/). It seems to work on chrome for me.

Comment: Thank you very much, but your solution is working on chrome for desktop. My problem is when I open it from a mobile. Open up that jsfiddle from your phone and you will see what Im talking about

Comment: I suspect it may have something to do with how the video is encoded. Can you post a link to the file?

Comment: Of course! [video](http://we.tl/kawYDEnxQ6) It is only about 4mb

Comment: Did you find a solution? I encounter the same issue with a mp4 video and is very boring : works on chrome PC but not on chrome android (with cordova).